# TinyMCE 5: Custom blockqote with (noneditable) cite

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-5

I'm using TinyMCE 5. By default, when you click on "blockquote" **button** (that is **on toolbar**) - it will insert the following HTML:

[image]

```html
<blockquote>
    <p>
        <br data-mce-bogus="1">
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

Or, if I select some text and then click on "blockquote" button, it will put it inside:

```html
<blockquote>
    <p>
        selected text
        <br data-mce-bogus="1">
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

I want to change this so that when you click on the *button that is on toolbar* - it will always insert `<cite class="mceNonEditable">Quote:</cite>` inside `<blockquote>` as the first element. Also, if possible, I would like to make this "cite" element non-editable.

```html
<blockquote>
    <cite class="mceNonEditable">Quote:</cite>
    <p>
        <br data-mce-bogus="1">
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

I've checked the following article and documentation, but couldn't find anything on how to achieve (implement) this:

- Blockquote CSS and styling in TinyMCE: https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/blockquote-css-and-styling-in-tinymce/
- Content formatting options: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting

I'm using TinyMCE **5**.

Fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Guhaab

---

**UPDATE (more details):**

[Dallas Clark suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64256540/4437206) using `::before` pseudo element before a Blockquote. It's interesting idea but there's this problem:

- Like any forum, each post will have "quote" button (link). When user clicks on it, backend (server-side) code will prepare the following HTML with "cite":

```html
<blockquote>
    <cite class="mceNonEditable">
        Originally posted by <a href="user_profile_page">John Doe</a>:
        <a class="pull-right" href="link_to_the_post"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
    </cite>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

Then user will be redirected to the form for creating a new post, which will have TinyMCE with that HTML.

If my site already applies the following CSS:

```css
        blockquote::before {
            content: "Quote:";
            color: #ff9c00;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

... then that "pseudo element" will always appear, even when there's already  "cite" element there.

That's why I was asking for adding non-editable "cite" element if user just clicks on "blockquote" button on TinyMCE toolbar.
I already asked about applying such CSS only if there's no "cite" element: [CSS: Apply blockquote::before only if it blockquote doesn't have <cite> element (without jQuery/JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64298862/css-apply-blockquotebefore-only-if-it-blockquote-doesnt-have-cite-element?noredirect=1#comment113700146_64298862) (but it's not possible without using JS/jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

Customising the HTML has some risks, as indicated by your blog post, you can add a `::before` pseudo element before a Blockquote within your TinyMCE content using CSS. The same CSS can be added to your website/application (where the content is displayed) to replicate the same functionality.

Simply add a `blockquote` style within `content_style` in your `init` function:

```
    ...
    content_style: `
        blockquote::before {
            color: #ff9c00;
            content: "Quote:";
            font-size: 0.6rem;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    `
    ...
```

This way, the content is not editable, it will always exist and you shouldn't have any issues when upgrading TinyMCE.

Check out the following [Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Luhaab) as an example.

Comment: Hi, I like the idea but there's problem: I updated my question and mentioned your answer.

Comment: This looks like a problem with existing data on the forum?

Comment: Yes, the existing blockquote that is loaded from backend will have `cite` with details about the author of the original post that was quoted (and link to that original post). On the other side, user can insert blockquotes that are not quoting posts, just by clicking on the "blockquote" button on toolbar of TinyMCE (so these blockquotes will not have `cite` with the details, just "Quote:"). Your solution with `::before` can be used in this case, I created a class with such CSS and now I just need to figure out this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64325041/4437206