# TinyMCE 5: Always add a class to blockquote element when inserting it (by clicking on the "blockquote" button on toolbar)

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

When user clicks on "blockquote" button (that is on toolbar) to insert `blockquote` element:

[image]

then TinyMCE will insert `<blockquote>` HTML element without any class. I want to change this so that it *always* inserts `<blockquote>` with class `myClass` (but *only* when blockquote is inserted by clicking on "toolbar" button, not when loaded):

```html
<blockquote class="myClass">
    ...
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

Do you know how this can be done/achieved?

I'm using TinyMCE **5**.

**Fiddle:** http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Guhaab

---

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, my question wasn't precise enough: I want this class to be added just for  elements added via the button, *not* when loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Updated Answer:***

The querent added:

> I want this class to be added just for elements added via the button, not when loaded.

In that case:
Blockquotes are added to content by applying a predefined, default format called (you guessed it) "blockquote". You can override that default style to include a class when it is applied to content:

```
formats: {
    // Changes the default format for blockquote to have a class of 'foo'
    blockquote: { block: 'blockquote', classes: 'foo' }
  },
```

Here is a Tiny Fiddle demonstration:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/svhaab/1

Here's information about formats in TinyMCE:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/

---

***Original Answer:***

One option would be to use a node filter to add this class to all `<blockquote>` elements:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.serializer/#addnodefilter
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.html/tinymce.html.domparser/#addnodefilter

Here is a Tiny Fiddle example:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/hvhaab/1
*(ETA correct Fiddle link)*

Note: As seen in the Fiddle, this approach will also add the class to `<blockquote>` elements that are loaded or pasted in to the editor as existing content - not just `<blockquote>` elements added via the button.

Also, if a `<blockquote>` element already has a (different) class, this will add your custom class to the attribute.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my question wasn't precise enough: I want this class to be added just for elements added via the button, not when loaded. I updated my question.

Comment: Response had been edited to include an approach to only apply this class to blockquotes added via the toolbar button.

Comment: Thanks. I also add `wrapper: true` because without it if you press enter - you will go out of blockquote.